# Monitoring Spring Security application with a bearer_tocken

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, prometheus

I want to set up monitoring Spring Security application, which has updated bearer token.
I connect monitoring using a combination of Grafana and Prometheus, but after a token refresh time, it disconnects.
The Spring Security application implements a token refresh mechanism after authorization.

pom.xml dependensies:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>io.micrometer.prometheus</groupId>
     <artifactId>prometheus-rsocket-spring</artifactId>
     <version>1.5.0</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
     <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

Example of the prometheus config file I use:

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'project_manager'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    bearer_token: 'my.bearer.tocken.example'
    metrics_path: '/api/actuator/prometheus'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['host.docker.internal:8200']
```

I tried use this settings in application:

```
management.security.enabled=false
management.metrics.sensitive=false
```

Monitoring works successfully for an hour, after which the token is updated and the connection between Prometheus and the application is lost.
Perhaps I can set up a refresh token in the prometneus configuration?

Comment: Show your security configuration. What kind of authentication do you use?

Comment: I think you can't do this with Prometheus *unless* you use client ID|secret instead of service accounts. I've solved this problem for myself (using Google Cloud services) by writing a simple authenticating proxy that runs with a service account as its identity, obtains access|ID tokens from the authorization server (and refreshes if appropriate). This adds some complexity although the proxy is trivial. There's an outstanding [issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/10339) against Prometheus